# Trying to get CSS working in my project - trying to troubleshoot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to get a css file to work in my react project. I've always used create-react-app in personal projects, but this project was created from webpack, so I have to configure the loaders and such and my understanding is limited. What's even worse is that, I inherited the project with all of the styling being applied for a styles object on each component, so there are multiple complexities here. But anywhozzle, the css file resides in the exact same folder as the component's JS file. I'm attempting to import the css style sheet as files in my Home component as follows:

```
import from './home.css'
```

The error I'm getting is...

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:12)
import from './home.css'
```

...and there's a red arrow pointing to the ' just before ./home.css.

The loader section of my webpack config file looks as follows:

```
module : {
  loaders : [
    {
      test : /\.jsx?/,
      include : APP_DIR,
      loader : 'babel-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        limit: 10000
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

and, for good measure, here's my package.json...

```
{
  "name": "react-cbd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "devNoServer": "webpack --d --watch",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --watch --progress --colors",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "font-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "0.0.3",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-carousel": "^2.2.1",
    "react-datetime": "^2.11.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scrollbars": "0.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.8",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to the import with the name of the component.

```
import ComponentName from './home.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, for css in react, it works with just importing the css module without from keyword:

`import './home.css'`

You can check [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) about imports in Javascript if you want to dig deeper.

Comment: That was my understanding as well, but putting in a dummy alias seems to have removed the error... although now I got a new one. Decided to put this on the side temporarily

Comment: default imports or alias for css are non sense, as you aren't using them in your code. It should work with that import. What's the new error?

Comment: ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./src/client/app/cbd-desktop/components/home/home.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './resources/desktop-img/section1_bg.jpg' in '/home/jordan/git/source/react-cbd/src/client/app/cbd-desktop/components/home'
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./src/client/app/cbd-desktop/components/home/home.css 7:81-131
 @ ./src/client/app/cbd-desktop/components/home/home.css
 @ ./src/client/app/cbd-desktop/components/home/Home.js
 @ ./src/client/app/index.jsx
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/client/app/index.jsx

Comment: Can you change the `use` in css loader for `loader: "style-loader!css-loader"` in the webpack configuration.
Are you using jpg files?

Comment: Check this answer for the `jpg` problem. The problem isn't with css, it is with jpg. Can you please remove the images and see if the style is rendered in the app.